# How can you (and should you) access flash, session, and controller instance variables from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I should start of by saying that this started from helpful messages like the one you get when you set up Devise (as of v. 2.2.3):

```
Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb 
For example:
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

There are at least three ways you can get information into a view from a controller. You can put things in the session, put then in the flash, or set an instance variable in the controller. I see examples where both the flash and the session are accessed with a bare variable in the view, which opens up the possibility of a collision. For example, I could have a controller like this:

```
class PerverseController < ApplicationController

def index
    @msg = 'Message 1'
    session[:msg] = 'Message 2'
    # Note - this is where a real concern comes in, the previous page could 
    # have done anything! Though here I use flash.now to illustrate the point.
    flash.now[:msg] = 'Message 3'
end
```

Then, if I had the following in a view:

```
<%= msg %>
```

It would seem that any of those three values might be referenced. In fact, code like the above in a view is an error for me (on Rails 3.2). You need to actually use '@' or 'flash' or 'session' explicitly.

I can't find any clear documentation on this - books and tutorials mostly reference the flash and the session as an afterthought, so I imagine it might change in future versions. But, I'd love to see a pointer to references, and a suggestion of what I *should* do to avoid breakage in the future while keeping my code as clear / concise as possible.

And for now, I want to make sure I integrate properly with Devise.

Comment: Apparently, there is a fourth way to pass information into a view, and that's what devise is doing. In this case, you effectively end up with a local variable in the view. This may or may not be the same sense in which the variables "flash" and "session" are available in the view. Anyway, still would be nice to have an overview / reference!

Comment: Just to add some notes here, though I wouldn't quite call it an answer yet: Devise apparently has two separate ways that it sets messages - one way is on the 'resource' which gets displayed by devise_error_messages! function (part of the default login form), and the flash. You can find other question on SO about this.